# I'm trying to start a react app but its not starting

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling

I installed react but now when im trying to start it is giving me this error:

```
$ npm start

> cred@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have `node_modules` folder in your project. If not, You can do `npm install` or `yarn` & then try running your project.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Cyebukayire yes, I found the solution, I was using that react-app in the d drive folder but when I installed it in c user drive the error has gone

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue a few minutes ago,
I tried to delete the `node modules` folder and `package-lock.json` as a solution suggested by other developers but this couldn't work for me.
So, after doing that, I closed my editor (vscode) and reopened it.
I did `npm start` in another new terminal and it worked.

If the above solution doesn't work for you, try [This source](https://sebhastian.com/react-scripts-not-recognized-fix/)